# Template for consultation/edition of a generic form field

Tags: mvvm, knockout.js

In my knockout form, I have a lot of code duplicate like this :

```
<div data-bind="if:Id == 0">
My form field : <input type="text" name="MyFormField" data-bind="value:MyFormField />
</div>
<div data-bind="if:Id != 0">
My form field consultable : <span data-bind="text:MyFormField"></span>
</div>
```

As you can see, if the Id = 0, I show a input, or a simple span if just for consultation.

Is it possible to make a generic template of this ?
The idea would be :

1. Call the template with a reference to the property i want to show
2. If Id == 0, the template render an input, instead, the template render a span

Thank's by advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at Note 5 of the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html), you can dynamically select which template you want to use for a section. In your case, it would be something like:

```
<ul data-bind='template: { name: templateName }'> </ul>
```

Then add a computed property to your view model:

```
templateName = ko.computed(function()
{
    return Id() === 0 ? 'inputTemplate' : 'spanTemplate';
});
```

And then have your two templates named the same as the two naming options in the computed:

```
<script type="text/html" id="inputTemplate">
    <input type="text" data-bind="text: name" />
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="spanTemplate">
    <span data-bind="text: name" />
</script>
```

Comment: I imagine the second template id (for span) is spanTemplate instead of Template. Apart that, it works. 
Thank you !